# Google Sheets conditional formatting based on age in hours

Tags: time

I'm trying to conditionally format a column, if the date/time value in the column D is less than 4 hours old, turns yellow. The custom formula I tried is this. Trying to search for solution but cant find much on it

Column D is formatted as "8/23  7:00"

```
=IF(timevalue($D$2)<NOW()-4)
```

Tried a different approach that didnt work

```
=isbetween(now(), now() - 1 / 24)
```

Also tried
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pl73L.png)

Answer (score 0):

is less than

```
=now() - 4 / 24
```

this worked, sheets was lagging to reflect the format

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).